# memoview inside cython structs... how to assign to them? (SIGSEGV)

Tags: struct, cython, segmentation-fault, memoryview

I think I have a similar issue:

I define a struct containing memoryviews:

```
ctypedef double[:] vector
ctypedef double[:,::1] matrix

ctypedef struct my_struct:
    matrix A
    vector b
```

Now I initialize such a struct with:

```
cdef my_struct *instance = <my_struct*>malloc(sizeof(my_struct))
instance.A = 2*np.eye(3, dtype='double')
instance.b = np.zeros((3,), dtype='double')

print(matmul(instance.A, instance.B))
```

Ignore `matmul` for now (it is a well tested cython function to compute matrix multiplication). The error I get is a SIGSEGV (11) at `instance.A = ...` assignment line. It seems that it should work (qua types). In fact, if A was not inside a struct this assignment would work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Struct definition with typed memoryview as member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482770/struct-definition-with-typed-memoryview-as-member)

Comment: The answer in the duplicate identifies the problem correctly. I wouldn't use their workround (it'll leak memory at the end) - instead I'd just accept that this is something that doesn't work.